# Determine string pattern "a+b"

Tags: java, regex

I am using String.matches() to determine if a string is in the following pattern:

"a+b", where a and b is a number (can contain both , and . if decimal number)

I wrote a regex for determining if a number is on the form I want, but I am struggling to write the regex for the whole thing.

For just a number, this is my code:

`kortform.matches("\\d+([\\,.]?\\d+)?")`

For "a+b" I have the following code, but "1+2" won't even work.

```
kortform.matches("\\d+([\\,.]?\\d+)?\\+\\\\d+([\\,.]?\\d+)?")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
kortform.matches("\\d+([,.]?\\d+)?[+]\\d+([,.]?\\d+)?")
```

- You don't need to escape `,`
- `+` can avoid escaping if used as `[+]` (character class)

#### Working Demo: http://ideone.com/OzVOQ7

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '+' near index 0

Comment: Are you sure you coped exact this regex? Since it worked in my testing?

Comment: I also provided a demo for you in my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am sorry to have wasted your time, I am very rusty in programming. I figured out that the following code was the error:
kortform.split("+") - It had to be kortform.split("\\+")

Comment: My initial code was wrong either way, so your answer helped :)

Comment: Glad to know it helped out sorting out your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
kortform.matches("\\d+([,.]\\d+)?\\+\\d+([,.]\\d+)?");
```

Comment: I get the following error:
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '+' near index 0

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
kortform.matches("\d+[\.\,]?(\d+)?\+\d+[\.\,]?(\d+)?")
```